# using ajax for acts_as_voteable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

im trying to use ajax on acts_as_votable gem so the page doesnt refresh on a vote/upvote. I've adjused the controller methods for this, and added remote true on the links. However i think the only thing left are the two .js.erb files. ive looked around on here and the ruby documentation and i cant seem to find how to do it for this instance. thanks

```js
VM23182:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
    at processResponse (application-50000f29e1bf2752ae7e56dda39f10dd0f67a47aea5c3f07ed0d933f3e1a256a.js:268)
    at application-50000f29e1bf2752ae7e56dda39f10dd0f67a47aea5c3f07ed0d933f3e1a256a.js:196
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (application-50000f29e1bf2752ae7e56dda39f10dd0f67a47aea5c3f07ed0d933f3e1a256a.js:251)
```

```js
`$('.unlike_post').bind('ajax:success', function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.vote_count').html('<%= escape_javascript @post.votes_for.size.to_s %>');
   $(this).closest('.unlike_post').hide();
   $(this).closest('.votes').html(' <%= link_to "Like", like_post_path(@post), remote: true, method: :get, class: "like_post" %>');

});`
```

```html
Started PUT "/tweets/60/like" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-02 00:06:40 +0100
Processing by TweetsController#upvote as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"60"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/benherring/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Tweet Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tweets".* FROM "tweets" WHERE "tweets"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 60], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:57
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."voter_id" = $3 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL AND "votes"."voter_type" = $4  [["votable_id", 60], ["votable_type", "Tweet"], ["voter_id", 3], ["voter_type", "User"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:58
  ActsAsVotable::Vote Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "votes".* FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."voter_id" = $3 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL AND "votes"."voter_type" = $4 ORDER BY "votes"."id" DESC LIMIT $5  [["votable_id", 60], ["votable_type", "Tweet"], ["voter_id", 3], ["voter_type", "User"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:58
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:58
  ActsAsVotable::Vote Update (0.5ms)  UPDATE "votes" SET "updated_at" = $1, "vote_flag" = $2 WHERE "votes"."id" = $3  [["updated_at", "2018-10-01 23:06:40.357671"], ["vote_flag", true], ["id", 10]]
  ↳ app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:58
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:58
  Rendering tweets/vote.js.erb
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."vote_flag" = $3  [["votable_id", 60], ["votable_type", "Tweet"], ["vote_flag", true]]
  ↳ app/views/tweets/_icons.html.erb:5
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."vote_flag" = $3  [["votable_id", 60], ["votable_type", "Tweet"], ["vote_flag", false]]
  ↳ app/views/tweets/_icons.html.erb:9
  Rendered tweets/_icons.html.erb (5.7ms)
  Rendered tweets/vote.js.erb (8.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 40ms (Views: 21.0ms | ActiveRecord: 4.7ms)
```

```html
resources :tweets do
  member do
    put "like", to: "tweets#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "tweets#downvote"
  end
```

```html
<div id="tweets">
  <% @tweets.each do |tweet|  %>
  <div class="card">

    <h4 class = "username"><%= link_to tweet.user.username, user_path(tweet.user) %></h4>
    <p class="tweet-content"><%= tweet.content %></p>
    <p class="date"><%= tweet.created_at.strftime("%B %d %Y, %l:%M%P") %></p>
    <div class="icons">

      <%= link_to like_tweet_path(tweet),remote: true , method: :put do %>
      <div class="upvote"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> <%= tweet.get_upvotes.size %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to dislike_tweet_path(tweet), remote: true, method: :put do %>
      <div><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i> <%= tweet.get_downvotes.size %></div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

```html
  def upvote
  @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
  @tweet.upvote_by current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to :tweets}
    format.js {render layout: false}
    # redirect_to :tweets
  # redirect_to :tweets
  #  if request.xhr?
  #   head :ok
  # else
  end
end

def downvote
  @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
  @tweet.downvote_by current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to :tweets}
    format.js {render layout: false}
  # redirect_to :tweets
end
end
```

Comment: What have you already tried for the js files?

Comment: ive attempted to change someone elses code to mine, but i cant see how to be honest. i'll add it to my question. im quite new to ajax.@ChrisHall

Comment: Just to encourage other answers, you might want to put the JS snippet after your opening paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the way you initially started on is to attach handlers to the buttons that listen for successful requests.  This is a fair way to do it, but - since you're already using Rails UJS - there's a possibly "better" way.

With Rails UJS, JS files returned from a remote action are automatically executed.  In my opinion, a more idiomatic Rails way to do this is as follows:

Extract out the icons into their own template:

```
<div id="tweets">
  <% @tweets.each do |tweet|  %>
  <div id="tweet-<%= tweet.id %>" class="card">

    <h4 class = "username"><%= link_to tweet.user.username, user_path(tweet.user) %></h4>
    <p class="tweet-content"><%= tweet.content %></p>
    <p class="date"><%= tweet.created_at.strftime("%B %d %Y, %l:%M%P") %></p>
    <%= render 'icons', tweet: tweet %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

`tweets/_icons.html.erb`:

```
<div class="icons">
  <%= link_to like_tweet_path(tweet),remote: true , method: :put do %>
    <div class="upvote"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> <%= tweet.get_upvotes.size %></div>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to dislike_tweet_path(tweet), remote: true, method: :put do %>
    <div class="downvote"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i> <%= tweet.get_downvotes.size %></div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Then, in your upvote/downvote controller actions you would `format.js { render 'vote' }` which would live at `tweets/vote.js.erb` and look like:

```
document.querySelector('#tweet-<%= @tweet.id %> .icons').outerHTML = '<%= j render('icons', tweet: @tweet) %>';
```

At this point, you're now free to modify `tweets/_icons.html.erb` to provide extra functionality (e.g. visual feedback on votes or changing the URL of the links to undo a vote).

---

#### Old jQuery method

Keeping this "older" jQuery method for those people who encounter a similar issue and are using jQuery.  Though, really, [you probably don't need it](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

```
$('#tweet-<%= @tweet.id %> .icons').replaceWith('<%= j render('icons', tweet: @tweet) %>');
```

Comment: thank you. i followed these steps however, when i click on an upvote/downvote  button i still need to refresh the page for the effect of the number going up to take place.

Comment: Are you sure the JS is able to target the card?  You may need to manually run some of the code or watch the network requests to see what's going on.  Most browsers have some form of JS Console / Network monitor.

Comment: im not too sure to be honest, but i've uploaded the log when i click on an upvote button from the terminal and the console in my original question, if that helps.

Comment: Ah, right, I forgot that Rails doesn't come bundled with jQuery anymore.  Let me fix that.